# Android URL scheme: intent.getData() == null (PhoneGap)

Tags: android, cordova, android-intent, url-scheme

So I'm trying to get a the URL being called into my app, but after it opens, it just always seems to be `null` not matter what I do.

Here's the relevant part of my manifest:

```
<activity android:name="myapp" android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale"
            android:launchMode="singleTask">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <data android:scheme="myapp" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

And here's my java:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {

    super.onStart();
    final Intent intent = getIntent();

    Uri url = intent.getData();

    Log.e("myLog", "Url = " + url);

}
```

The log is outputting "Intent = null", and I have no errors.

I'm not a java developer so I may have a simple problem I don't recognize. I'm going to pass this into my PhoneGap app with `sendJavascript` but being a PhoneGap app doesn't seem relevant to this issue.

EDIT:

I seem to only be getting the first `<intent-filter>` when I log `intent`. Here's the log:

```
03-13 12:36:18.593: E/MyAppLog(13793): Intent=Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.wd.myapp/.myapp (has extras) }
```

---

SOLUTION:

After pouring through dozens of posts on how to implement URL schemes to open your PhoneGap app, and none of them being very robust or working at all, I'm going to post my full solution and hope someone finds it useful.

Step one: AndroidManifest.xml - Add this `<intent-filter>` to your `<activity>`, changing 'urlScheme' to whatever you like. In this case, you could click a link to urlScheme:///?key=val and it would open the app.

```
<intent-filter>
    <data android:scheme="urlScheme" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
</intent-filter>
```

Step Two: myApp.java - Add the following underneath `onCreate`. If you are using `singleTask`, be sure to put your `intent` logic in the `onStart` function (instead of in `onCreate`, as others have trumpeted), as that will allow you to link into your app whether it's already running or not.

```
@Override
public void onStart() {

    super.onStart();
    final Intent intent = getIntent();

    String url = intent.getDataString();

    if(url != "" && url != null) {
        super.sendJavascript("setTimeout(function() { handleOpenURL('" + url + "'); },1);");
    }                


}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
     super.onNewIntent(intent); setIntent(intent);
}
```

See the accepted answer for an explanation of the `onNewIntent` override.

Comment: I think final Intent intent = getIntent(); should be final Intent intent = intent.getIntent();

Comment: How so? 'intent' doesn't exist yet. I'll try it though.

Comment: Yeah, it's not a method. I believe I logged `intent` as is and got something from it. It's just calling methods on it to get data out of it is always null.

Comment: try to override `onNewIntent`.     `@Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        setIntent(intent);
    }`

Comment: @dg988 Your problem get solved?

Comment: No. I tried your answer, but I had tried getting the string, but same problem. Using the `if` in your answer, though, I'm hitting an `else` case I added.

Comment: @vmironov I somehow missed your comment. Your solution worked! Thank you! If you create an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: I may just be understanding something wrong but I followed these instructions using `tagcalhoun` for the scheme, but if I go to `tagcalhoun:///?s=1` in the browser it does a google search. I thought that should have been enough to trigger it. Am I missing something or is my understanding of how I can trigger the intent wrong?

Comment: Create an actual html link somewhere that you can click and it should work.

Comment: After super.sendJavascript("..."); you should call getIntent().setData(null);

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try to override `onNewIntent`. The problem is that `getIntent` returns the `Intent` that started the `Activity`, but not the most recent one. But you can override it using `setIntent` method.

```
@Override 
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) { 
    super.onNewIntent(intent); 
    setIntent(intent); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks works like a charm. Only thing I have to do on my solution is. As I was launching a new activity say ActivityZ from my main activity, in my onStart method. But what was happening as whenever I come back to main activity it again launches ActivityZ, so what I did is explicitly setting intent data to null.

Comment: it is so unbelievable, that you have to overwrite onNewIntent. android is an effing joke.

Answer (score 0):

Extending original answer, in case your main activity launches another activity. Then it can end up an infinite loops of launching the activity again and again as you come back to main activity from the launched activity.

Here is the code

```
public void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Uri data = intent.getData();
        if (data != null) {
            // explicitly set intent data to null
            // so on next launch, from same lifecycle of activity
            // it does not restart the Activity Z.
            intent.setData(null);
            Intent activityZ = new Intent(MyActivity.this, ActivityZ.class);
                businessViewActivity.putExtra("url", data.toString());
                startActivity(activityZ);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        setIntent(intent);
    }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: You need to set android:launchMode="singleTask" on the activity in your AndroidManifest.xml (see the code in the question)